# Characterizing clusters by separate feature vector scores

Tags: clustering, manova, characteristic-function

Say I have a medium amount of dependent variables in a study. These are scores from questionnaires that have been standardized so all are on a scale from 0 to 1.

I have clusters of my patients - determined by another method - and I want to use a method to characterize the patients in each cluster as distinguished from patients in the other clusters. Let's say I have 5 clusters.

Is there a method that anyone knows about that can detect these "threshold relationships" automatically? I worry my results will be complicated and I may not be able to "see" how cluster 1 and cluster 2,3,4,5 differ by their questionnaire scores (or determine if they don't, statistically).

I want a rigorous, non eye-balled approach, if that makes sense. Rules I end up will look like the following characterizations:

```
Cluster 1: Score1>=0.8, Score2<=0.4, Score3>=0.8, ...
Cluster 2: Score1<=0.2, Score2>=0.6, Score3<=0.2, ...
Cluster 3: Score1>=0.4, Score2<=0.7, Score3<=0.5, ...
```

And then a significance value for each cluster against the rest... Could I use a multi-way ANOVA for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **decision tree**.

You are looking for an interpretable *classifier*, not a clustering. You already did clustering, and you are using that as classes now.

Comment: I love it - I will definitely look into this!